# Powershell: Split string and insert before second capital letter

Tags: powershell, split

I have a string which is a combination of several words.
What is the best way in `Powershell` to remove text in string after `_` and insert `.` before second capital character? For example:

```
$name = SomeWords_SomeString_123.txt
```

What should be received:

```
$a=SomeWords
$b=Some.Words
```

Can this be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regex oneliner. 
split string on the first `_`
insert a `.` before every uppercase letter but not at the start of the word.

`-creplace` - case-sensitive replace operation

```
($name -split '_')[0] -creplace '(?<=\w)([A-Z])', '.$1'
```

Comment: Thanks. Very useful.